# Defining algorithms mathematically

Tags: algorithms, definition

Looking from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm), it says that an algorithm is a finite sequence of rigorous instructions. However, what is the mathematical definition of an algorithm, and how can I show that the set of all algorithms is countably infinite? That is probably the same as being able to start listing algorithms in some logical order.

Comment: There is no one rigorous definition of an algorithm. A common approach is to use Turing Machines to model algorithms. But the Church-Turing thesis - that Turing Machines successfully model everything we think of as an algorithm - is not a theorem, just a belief. Other models of computation, for example, using lambda calculus, are known to be equivalent to Turing machines.

Comment: I’ve always found Markov algorithms a more intuitive way to model algorithms than Turing machines. But Turing machines are simpler, in that it is easier to model a Turing machine as a Markov algorithm than visa versa. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_algorithm

Comment: The "brute force" way: if you accept that an algorithm is of finite length with a finite number of possible characters, it's upper bounded by all finite length texts with a finite alphabet, and is thus a subset of |N. To go the other way, note you can print create the algorithm `print 1; print 2; print 3; ....` to any length

Comment: The reason it's countably infinite is that the instruction set is finite. You can see this is the case because the set of finite length strings is countably infinite and the set of instructions is a subset of all finite length strings.

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that an algorithm is a finite sequence of functions: $(f_1, f_2, \dots, f_N)$ so that the domain of $f_{i+1}$ is the codomain of $f_i$?

Comment: @mathslover You need a lot of care that you're not taking unreasonable/uncomputable functions. One approach that works is ["general recursive functions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_recursive_function).